# Unity Gradle Syntax Error: Unexpected Input '{' in Android build.gradle File

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm facing an issue while trying to compile my Android project using Gradle. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\...\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\jmb71\Desktop\PixelDash\Jackal\Jackal\Unity Project - Jackal Internal\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\...\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle': 7: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 7, column 9.
     android {
             ^
  
  1 error
```

Im using Unity 2022.3.8f1

I've made sure that in Unity external tools preferences im using all of the recommended checkboxes for everything.
[unity preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ZSY.png)

Here is the contents of the build.gradle file supposedly having the issue:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    }

android {
    ndkPath "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.8f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK"

    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 34
        applicationId 'com.company.project'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        versionCode 1
        versionName 'v0.2-115-g494f40183
'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.bundle', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me identify and resolve the syntax error in my Gradle build file?

Comment: There's a single quote character `'` on the line below `versionName` that probably shouldn't be there, or it looks like it should be on the previous line at the and of the version.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I saw that as well, however when i fix it and hit build again, but it just rengerates the file or something and comes right back :(

Comment: I'd take a look at the Android player settings and make sure there isn't anything weird in the Version field under Identification. The documentation says it should be just numbers and dots. You might try that just to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @RetiredNinja i changed the vresion field to just be "1" but I still get the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Fix the  '  in your file.

Like SimonC said, it belongs to the end of the line above it.

**And no, do NOT edit the file under "{Project}/library/bee/android"    It is auto-generated!**

**The file you want to edit is: "Assets/Plugin/Android/mainTemplate.gradle"**

You update the mainTemplate.gradle, its content will be copied into that one under library

Comment: Are you sure the apostrophe needs to be removed? Looks more like it should be moved to the end of the previous line.

Comment: You are correct. I apologize.   But my point stands:  Edit the "mainTemplate.gradle" file in the Plugins/Android directory